# How to find how many number in each digits Python

Tags: python

Example start with

```
number= int(input())
```

if I enter 87576

it will come out something like this

```
digit 5 has 1
digit 6 has 1
digit 7 has 2
digit 8 has 1
```

*I really have no idea how to solve this ....help..
*Python

Comment: did you try anything so far?

Comment: The question is not clear at all. Please explain it clearly? Please define your problem clearly.

Comment: Create empty dictionary. Loop over the string `'87576'`, check if current character is in dictionary, if yes add 1 to it, if not, add the character as key, and assign its value as 1.

Comment: @SayandipDutta could you mind make an example for me it sound like what i am trying to do but i just can't figure out how to do...

Comment: Sure, give me a moment.

Comment: @Steven21 you can check now.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
from collections import Counter
number = '87576'
cn = Counter(number)
print(cn)
```

Answer (score 1):

So there are a lot of methods. Let's start from basic to the advanced.

```
inp = '87576'
dct = {}
for dig in inp:
    if dig not in dct:
        dct[dig] = 1
    else:
        dct[dig] += 1
for dig in sorted(dct):
    print(f"digit {dig} has {dct[dig]}")
```

Second method:

```
inp = '87576'
dct = {}
for dig in inp:
    dct[dig] = dct.get(dig,0) + 1
for dig in sorted(dct):
    print(f"digit {dig} has {dct[dig]}")
```

Third method:

```
inp = '87576'
dct = dict.fromkeys(inp,0)
for dig in inp:
    dct[dig] += 1
for dig in sorted(dct):
    print(f"digit {dig} has {dct[dig]}")
```

Fourth method:

```
inp = '87576'
dct = {dig: inp.count(dig) for dig in inp}
for dig in sorted(dct):
    print(f"digit {dig} has {dct[dig]}")
```

Fifth method:

```
inp = '87576'
for dig in sorted(set(inp)):
    print(f"digit {dig} has {inp.count(dig)}")
```

Sixth method:

```
from collections import defaultdict
inp = '87576'
dct = defaultdict(int)
for dig in inp:
    dct[dig] += 1
for dig in sorted(dct):
    print(f"digit {dig} has {dct[dig]}")
```

Seventh method (As others have mentioned here):

```
from collections import Counter
inp = '87576'
dct = Counter(inp)
for dig in sorted(dct):
    print(f"digit {dig} has {dct[dig]}")
```

Output:

```
digit 5 has 1
digit 6 has 1
digit 7 has 2
digit 8 has 1
```

**EDIT**:

I see you are looking for a solution with integers:

```
import math
inp = int('87576')
digits = ((inp//10**i)%10 for i in range(math.ceil(math.log(inp,10))))
dct = defaultdict(int)
for dig in digits:
    dct[dig] += 1
for dig in sorted(dct):
    print(f"digit {dig} has {dct[dig]}")
```

Comment: Appreciate it buddy, the first method is just fine !

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
from collections import Counter
Counter(str(number))
# Counter({'8': 1, '7': 2, '5': 1, '6': 1})
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer:

```
chars = "0123456789"
number = int(input("enter number: "))

for char in chars:
  count = str(number).count(char)
  if count > 0:
    print('digit {} has {}'.format(char,count))
```

Comment: This is perfect but is it possible to make the number input as number and not string ? like number=int(input())

Answer (score 0):

I assume you meant to ask number of occurrences of each digit in a number.

step1 : convert number to list of integer , and maintain a set for unique digits in a number

```
res = [int(x) for x in str(number)] 
res1 = set(res)
```

step2 : write a method to count the occurrence of a digit in a list

```
def countX(lst, x): 
return lst.count(x)
```

step3: call the countX method for each digit.

```
for val in res1:
    print('digit {} has {}'.format(val,countX(res,val)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach will be,

```
from collections import defaultdict

number = input()

digits_frequency = defaultdict(int)

while number:
    digit = number % 10
    digits_frequency[digit] += 1
    number //= 10

print(digits_frequency)
```

Output:

```
defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {8: 1, 5: 1, 6: 1, 7: 2})
```

You can also convert the number into a string for easy iteration.

```
from collections import defaultdict

number = str(input())

digits_frequency = defaultdict(int)

for digit in number:
    digits_frequency[digit] += 1

print(digits_frequency)
```

Time complexity:
O(N) as we are iterating the input once.

Answer (score 0):

You should use 'Counter' to count the number of digit and 'sorted' method to sort the Counted digit.

```
from collections import Counter

number= 87576
count_dict = Counter(str(number))

print(dict(sorted(count_dict.items())))
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
{'5': 1, '6': 1, '7': 2, '8': 1}
```